# Has anyone tried creating records of case related (look-up or master-detail) objects using salesforce Web to Case?

Tags: web2case

I have an object that has a look-up relation with Case object. While setting up Web to Case I want to add fields from related object. I know that we can choose from Case fields while setting up the form but is there any work-around to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other solutions proposed are fine, but the cleanest way to do this would be building an apex web service on a public site.

This will allow you to capture the form input, create the necessary records, put the needed data on each, and relate them together, which is unfortunately not available out-of-box with web-to-case.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the 'fields' you want to be in your other object on the Case Object you can then set a Process Builder to fire and create them in that new Object.  I know its double the effort in terms of field creation, but it is the easiest way to get the desired outcome that you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, agree this will work for 1:1 relationship.In my requirement the related object  has 1:M relationship with Case. For 1 Case record i have to create multiple records of related object.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a direct way for that, you will have to do a 2 step process there like setting up a Process Builder or a trigger to make sure data is getting populated properly.

Anyways, in a normal web to case form it will be difficult to create actual look up data in the HTML web site where you will be using the form.

Ray